# Codeigniter unset session

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

Hi I have a site develop in CodeIgniter.

In one of my page I'm using pagination of CodeIgniter after a search form.

In this case I store into my session the search value passed by `$_POST` because if I have more result clicking the next page the search keppe the searching value.

But when I change page for example I want to return to the index and after return to my search form page the session is already created and make the query with the value of the session. How can I destroy or unset the value of the session when I change page? Is this possible?

Into my model function I check if the session value is different from 0 and exist, if true I make a query with the session value.

This is my controller (nation is the value to store into the session)

```
public function region_list(){
        $this->load->model('backend/Nation_model');
        $this->load->library("pagination");

        if($_POST)
        {
            if (isset($_POST['ricerca'])){

                $nation = $this->input->post('nation');
                if(strlen($nation) > 0){
                   $this->session->set_userdata('nation',$nation);
                }

                $config = array();
                $config["base_url"] = base_url() . "index.php/backend/region/region_list";
                $config["total_rows"] = $this->Region_model->countRegionSearch();
                $config["per_page"] = 10;
                $config["uri_segment"] = 4;

                $this->pagination->initialize($config);

                $page = ($this->uri->segment(4)) ? $this->uri->segment(4) : 0;
                $data["regionlist"] = $this->Region_model->regionSearch($config["per_page"], $page);
                $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();
                $data["nationlist"] = $this->Nation_model->nationList();

                $this->load->view('backend/region_list_view',$data);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $config = array();
            $config["base_url"] = base_url() . "index.php/backend/region/region_list";
            $config["total_rows"] = $this->Region_model->countRegion();
            $config["per_page"] = 10;
            $config["uri_segment"] = 4;

            $this->pagination->initialize($config);

            $page = ($this->uri->segment(4)) ? $this->uri->segment(4) : 0;
            $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();
            $data["regionlist"] = $this->Region_model->regionList($config["per_page"], $page);
            $data["nationlist"] = $this->Nation_model->nationList();

            $this->load->view('backend/region_list_view',$data);
        }
    }
```

and this is my model to search:

```
function regionList($limit=null, $start=null) {
        $nation_id = $this->session->userdata('nation');
        if ($this->session->userdata('language')=="it")
            $this->db->select('region.id, region.name_it as name,nation.id as nation_id, nation.name_it as nation_name');
        if ($this->session->userdata('language')=="en")
            $this->db->select('region.id, region.name_en as name,nation.id as nation_id, nation.name_en as nation_name');
        $this->db->from('region');
        $this->db->join('nation', 'region.nation_id = nation.id','left');
        if((isset($nation_id))&&($nation_id!=0))
            $this->db->where('region.nation_id', $nation_id);
        $this->db->order_by("name", "asc");
        $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $region = array();
        foreach ($query->result() as $row)
            array_push($region, $row);

        return $region;     
    }

    function countRegion() {
        $nation_id = $this->session->userdata('nation');
        if ($this->session->userdata('language')=="it")
            $this->db->select('region.id, region.name_it as name,nation.id as nation_id, nation.name_it as nation_name');
        if ($this->session->userdata('language')=="en")
            $this->db->select('region.id, region.name_en as name,nation.id as nation_id, nation.name_en as nation_name');
        $this->db->from('region');
        $this->db->join('nation', 'region.nation_id = nation.id','left');
        if((isset($nation_id))&&($nation_id!=0))
            $this->db->where('region.nation_id', $nation_id);
        $this->db->order_by("name", "asc");
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->num_rows();  
    }

    public function regionSearch($limit=null, $start=null){
        $nation_id = $this->session->userdata('nation');
        if ($this->session->userdata('language')=="it"){
            $this->db->select('*,region.id, region.name_it as name,nation.id as nation_id, nation.name_it as nation_name');
            if($this->input->post('name')!="")
                $this->db->where('region.name_it LIKE "%'.$this->input->post('name').'%"');
        }

        if ($this->session->userdata('language')=="en"){
            $this->db->select('*,region.id, region.name_en as name,nation.id as nation_id, nation.name_en as nation_name');
            if($this->input->post('name')!="")
                $this->db->where('region.name_en LIKE "%'.$this->input->post('name').'%"');
        }
        $this->db->from('region');
        $this->db->join('nation', 'region.nation_id = nation.id','left');
        if((isset($nation_id))&&($nation_id!=0))
            $this->db->where('region.nation_id', $nation_id);
        $this->db->order_by("name", "asc");
        $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $region = array();
        foreach ($query->result() as $row)
            array_push($region, $row);

        return $region; 
     }

     public function countRegionSearch(){
        $nation_id = $this->session->userdata('nation');
        if ($this->session->userdata('language')=="it"){
            $this->db->select('*,region.id, region.name_it as name,nation.id as nation_id, nation.name_it as nation_name');
            if($this->input->post('name')!="")
                $this->db->where('region.name_it LIKE "%'.$this->input->post('name').'%"');
        }

        if ($this->session->userdata('language')=="en"){
            $this->db->select('*,region.id, region.name_en as name,nation.id as nation_id, nation.name_en as nation_name');
            if($this->input->post('name')!="")
                $this->db->where('region.name_en LIKE "%'.$this->input->post('name').'%"');
        }
        $this->db->from('region');
        $this->db->join('nation', 'region.nation_id = nation.id','left');
        if((isset($nation_id))&&($nation_id!=0))
            $this->db->where('region.nation_id', $nation_id);
        $this->db->order_by("name", "asc");

        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->num_rows();      
     }
```

Comment: Could you perhaps use GET vars in the URLs instead of persisting the search term in session?

Comment: If I have 10 or more input? A bad very bad URL

Comment: Fair enough. Not having used codeigniter before, does it use a front controller? If so maybe check the URL and if it's not the search page unset the session var. Bit of a stab in the dark I'm afraid.

Comment: I considered best practice to have the search terms in the URL, so that users could bookmark/share search results. Trust me users don't care about how ugly a url is... in fact most of them don't know what a URL is.

Comment: `$this->session->unset_userdata('nation');` will unset the session key called `nation`.

Comment: I know how to unset a session var @Gavin

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri - You may need to edit your question, as it appears you are asking how to unset a session variable?

Comment: Also keep in mind that a user might use multiple windows / tabs to view the site, if you start removing session vars that search is using  the user might get odd results.

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri - A better solution would be to use `FlashData`, i.e. `$this->session->set_flashdata('nation', $nation);` see http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html `CodeIgniter supports "flashdata", or session data that will only be available for the next server request, and are then automatically cleared.`

Comment: @JonStirling ok, but the problem is: I have the pagination and the pagination search the fourth parameter for the pagination, how can I add to my url the input value if is set? Because I have a button and transform It into a link... I don't think is a good idea

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri Like I said, I've no experience with codeigniter, so I'm limited in what I can suggest.

Comment: @JonStirling why odd result?

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri Say they had 2 tabs open, one of the was a search (and you're using sessions to store the search terms). Now, they navigate around the site on the other then come back to the search and click the next page, there is now no search term available (because it's been removed due to their other tabs browsing) and they have to start from scratch.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

answering to your question:

> How can I destroy or unset the value of the session?

I can help you by this:

```
$this->session->unset_userdata('some_name');
```

and for multiple data you can:

```
$array_items = array('username' => '', 'email' => '');

$this->session->unset_userdata($array_items);
```

and to destroy the session:

```
$this->session->sess_destroy();
```

Now for the on page change part  **(on the top of my mind)**:

> you can set the **config "anchor_class"** of the *paginator* equal to the **classname** you want.

after that just check it with **jquery onclick for that class** which will send a head up to the controller function that will unset the user session.

Comment: In array, 'username' is a column name ?

Comment: @DanishEnam yes it is!

Answer (score 7):

Instead of use set_userdata you should use set_flashdata.

According to CI user guide:

> CodeIgniter supports "flashdata", or session data that will only be available for the next server request, and are then automatically cleared. These can be very useful, and are typically used for informational or status messages (for example: "record 2 deleted").

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html

Answer (score 4):

```
$session_data = array('username' =>"shashikant");
$this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $session_data);

$this->session->unset_userdata('logged_in');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$this->session->unset_userdata('session_value');
```

Answer (score 1):

I use the old PHP way..It unsets all session variables and doesn't require to specify each one of them in an array. And after unsetting the variables we destroy the session.

```
session_unset();
session_destroy();
```

Answer (score -1):

I use the old PHP way..It unsets all session variables and doesn't require to specify each one of them in an array. And after unsetting the variables we destroy the session

Comment: And after unsetting the variables we destroy the session

Comment: And after unsetting the variables we destroy the session

Comment: And what exactly is that old way? Not to mention your comments repeat a part of the answer.