# How to destroy the session in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

How to destroy the session in codeigniter?

```
        error_reporting(0);
        $this->load->view('index');
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->load->helper(array('form','url'));
        $email    =$this->input->post("email");
        $password  =$this->input->post("password");
        $stmt = $this->db->query("select * from tbl_employees where email='".$email."' and password='".$password."'"); 
        $rowcount = $stmt->num_rows();
        if($rowcount==1) {
        foreach ($stmt->result() as $row)
        {
           $_SESSION['employee_id']=$row->employee_id;
           $_SESSION['first_name']=$row->first_name; 
           $_SESSION['last_name']=$row->last_name;
           print_r($_SESSION); 
           $this->session->sess_destroy();
           redirect('Dashboard/dashboard_index');
           $this->session->sess_destroy();
        }
```

Comment: $this->session->sess_destroy(); or session_destroy(); for CI3

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#destroying-a-session

Comment: What is the issue? You are destroying user session by `$this->session->sess_destroy();` so whats problem in it

Comment: it's is not destroying the session

Comment: Why do you say it is *not* destroying the session?  What happens instead?

Comment: Also, please **do not** store passwords in plaintext.  Always store their hash.  See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/549/the-definitive-guide-to-form-based-website-authentication/477578#477578).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Codeigniter unset session](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14233595/codeigniter-unset-session)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this: [Session Class](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/libraries/sessions.html)

> Note: The Session class does not utilize native PHP sessions. It generates its own session data, offering more flexibility for developers.

This is a wrong use codeigniter:

```
$_SESSION['employee_id']=$row->employee_id;
```

Try this:

```
$this->session->set_userdata('employee_id', $row->employee_id);
```