# Unset userdata before redirecting to another page in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, redirect

I am trying to reset/clear a specific session value in codeigniter right before the page redirect happens but it still keeps the value in session and doesn't clear it. If I comment the code that redirects the page, then it clears the session value. Below is the code I am using :

```
$this->session->set_userdata('my_session_variable', '');
$this->session->unset_userdata('my_session_variable');
redirect($my_url);
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: also destroy session after unset : $this->session->sess_destroy();
Check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14233595/codeigniter-unset-session?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: But that will clear all the sessions right? I want to clear specific session variable only.

Comment: If it refuses to unset, could you change the value to false (or 0) and use that as the 'unset' test value? It feels really hacky just typing this. =(

Comment: I am already doing it. See the first line in my code :)

Answer (score 0):

**Set Session Userdata**

```
$data = array(
            'name' => 'username',
            'user_id' => 'someid',
            'logged_in' => TRUE,
        );
$this->session->set_userdata($data);
```

**Unset Userdata**

```
$data = array('name', 'user_id', 'logged_in');
$this->session->unset_userdata($data);
redirect($my_url);
```

Comment: It's using Array. But I am not using an array.

Comment: you want single value in session?

Comment: Check the first line in my code, I am making it empty before unsetting it

$this->session->set_userdata('my_session_variable', '');

Comment: So your code is proper. but other issue need to fix

Comment: Yes still after doing 2 different things 1.empty the value and 2.unset the value. the session is not clearing

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->session->unset_userdata('my_session_variable');
```

...should work. Just for debug and see what is going on, you can do:

```
$this->session->unset_userdata('my_session_variable');
var_dump($_SESSION); 
die;
```

...and see what happens. If it works as expected, remove the `die;` add the same `var_dump()` at the very begining of the redirected page.

Remember that you can always do:

```
unset($_SESSION['my_session_variable']);
```

...to remove session data. More info [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#id10).

Comment: As I tried commenting out the redirect code clears the session. It's the same thing if I do the "die" before redirecting. It clears the session.

Comment: (edited) Try adding the `var_dump()` at the very begining of the redirected page, as I mention.

Comment: OK I tried it, infact I just did this as the first this of control loading
print_r($this->session->all_userdata());
After redirect, it goes empty but if I hit refresh on the page, it's back :S
To make this full proof, I am also unsetting this session on controller code

Comment: OK it seems that the normal variable I am using to store in the session data is linked some way with session variable 
so e.g.
It is like below
$my_number = 123;
$this->session->set_userdata('my_session_variable', $my_number);

Now if I change the value of $my_number to, it changes the session value>
But if I change the session directly with blank '', it doesn't work.